# PJSIP Build error - Library is not found

Tags: macos, ios7, xcode5, pjsip

I am following through this link `http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#BuildingPJSIP .`
 I am using `Mac OsX 10.9.2, xcode 5.1.1, ios sdk 7.1,` please correct me.

```
ld: library not found for -lmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you consider using prebuild pjsip binaries from here https://github.com/chebur/pjsip